# Carousel fade effect

Tags: html, css, carousel

I am looking to create a fade effect on a carousel where the images will fade into each other.

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carousel"></li>
        <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel"></li>
        <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carousel"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
            <section class="main-hero hero-light-text">
                <div class="container">
                </div><img class="main-image" src="/wp-content/themes/custom/images/1.jpg">
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
                <div class="container">
                </div><img class="main-image" src="/wp-content/themes/custom/images/2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <section class="main-hero hero-light-text">
                <div class="container">
                </div><img class="main-image" src="/wp-content/themes/custom/images/3.jpg">
            </section>
        </div>
    </div><a class="carousel-control left" data-slide="prev" href="#carousel">‹</a> <a class="carousel-control right" data-slide="next" href="#carousel">›</a>
</div>
```

How can I manipulate the css so that the images will fade into each other rather than them just switching without any effect.

```
<style>
.carousel-inner {
    width: auto;

    max-height: 600px
}
.carousel .item {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 3s; 
    -moz-transition: opacity 3s; 
    -ms-transition: opacity 3s; 
    -o-transition: opacity 3s; 
    transition: opacity 3s;
}
.carousel .active.left {
    left:0;opacity:0;z-index:2;
}
.carousel .next {
    left:0;opacity:1;z-index:1;
}
</style>
```

Comment: here you will not be able to reach your CSS selector with `.carousel .active.left`. Because your `div class="item"` have the active class additionnaly, but not the "left" one. I think you should try without the .left in your CSS selector

But you are close to it, you need to play with opacity and you can totally use transitions to manage the fading effect.

Comment: @Alex thanks , I removed .left and I was able to play around with the opacity and got it working.